# How to set all attributes to UploadedFile in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I've an API and I send a image from Angular Client in Base64, I've the next code for my method create:

```
if params[:profile][:picture]
        picture_params = params[:profile][:picture]


        #Create new Temporal File 
        temp_file = Tempfile.new("file_to_upload")
        temp_file.binmode
        temp_file.write(Base64.decode64(picture_params["body"]))

        #Create a new uploaded file
               uploaded_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
                :tempfile => temp_file, 
                :original_filename => picture_params[:name]) 

        #After replace picture with the new uploaded file
        params[:profile][:picture] = uploaded_file
        Rails.logger.info "#{params[:profile]}"
    end

    @profile = @current_user.build_profile(profile_params)
    if @profile.save
        render "api/v1/profiles/show"
    else
        errors_array!(@profile.errors.full_messages, :unprocessable_entity)
    end
```

After when I print my params the information is nil

```
"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f872daac5b0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/nx/30024wp17ggfgw542lyzs4zw0000gn/T/file_to_upload20160225-14952-by947r>, @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil, @headers=nil>}
```

And after when try to create the profile I've the next error, I think that is for the previous problem

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass):
 app/controllers/api/v1/profiles_controller.rb:39:in `create'
```

I use the paperclip gem for upload files in Rails 4.2.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for watching, but Have a solution, I changed my method:

```
    def set_selfies(selfie_params)
      picture_params = selfie_params
      encoded_picture = picture_params[:body]
      content_type = picture_params[:content_type]
      image = Paperclip.io_adapters.for("#{encoded_picture}")
      image.original_filename = picture_params[:name]
      image
    end
```

[I Read this Blog:](http://manukall.de/2015/04/30/saving-base64-encoded-data-as-paperclip-4-attachments/)
And That's all, works for me, Thanks :D